# How do I workout relevant annotations for a map depending on zoom level?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mapkit

I am using Xamarin with MapUIKit to show a map of the UK which will have a lot of annotation (potentially as many as 800)

Each annotation is a pin which I want the user to be able to click on to get more information

Apple seem to be suggesting that only the valid annotations should be rendered, depending on the zoom level

However, how do I work out which ones are actually needed?

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MKMapView [GetAnnotations](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMonoTouch.MapKit.MKMapView.GetAnnotations) to determine which annotations are contained in a specific view.

Comment: Thanks Jason how do I provide the actual map area which is required I.e is visible? Since I posted this I have come across xamarin forms which I may end up using if I can get round the pin colour issue I have just asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746338/change-pins-when-using-xamarin-forms-map If I use xamarin forms I don't need to do anything with this do I? I hope xamarin would deal with it as part of the translation to native code

Comment: MKMapView VisibleMapRect will return the MapRect for your current zoom/pan level