# Change pins when using xamarin.forms map

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

It appears as though I am likely to need to go down the xamarin forms route for my app development

However I have spotted a nasty problem

My users want different coloured pins

If a location has energy consumption above target the pins for those points need to be red. Below target green and on target orange

I know how to do this using the native mapkit in iOS but how can I do this in xamarin forms?

Is there a way of hooking in to the pin drawing code and overriding its behaviour?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

The current Map control provided with Forms is pretty bare bones.  Your best bet would be to create a platform specific map view and then call it via [DependencyService](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/), or create your own Map control and use a [custom renderer](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/).

Comment: Ok I think I will take a look at the dependency service and will Google too in a bit hopefully someone will have tried this before I think a custom control and renderer may be a lot more complex and I have got this functionality working in a native mapview for iOS

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what you mean by platform specific view please? I am sure that using the dependency service is the way to go but it's tricky as the example for xamarin does something totally different lol I just want to start simple really like trying to get a native mapkit to show inside a xamarin forms page

Comment: take the iOS MapView you've already written, and then use the DependencyService to call it from within a Forms app.  You would also have to write an Android implementation if you want to support Android also.

Comment: The map view is inside a story board at the moment and uses a delegate to customize the pins which is where things get tricky! I do want to support android but have not really looked at that yet want to get iOS working first

Comment: You should be able to do that from within a DIService

Comment: ok I will keep looking, I cant find any examples anywhere at the moment, not even simple ones as a starting point :(

Comment: Hmmm I have just watched the xamarin conference and I am now thinking about trying a renderer when I get to a computer instead of dependency resolver. However before I go down that route is there anything that would make the dependency revolver a better approach? I am only really shying way from it cos I can't find good examples close to what I am trying to do

Comment: I tend to favor DI just because that's what I've done before and I know how to make it work.  I think the key benefit of a Renderer is that it allows you to mix a platform specific view with other XF content on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this awesome Xamarin.Forms (iOS/Android) map project and change the custom pin images/colours accordingly.

https://github.com/raechten/BindableMapTest

Good luck!